# fail2ban and tomcat8 log filtered localhost_access_log : No such file or directory

Tags: tomcat, fail2ban

this is my first question on serverfault ;)

My conf : Debian 9.6, tomcat  8.5.14.0, fail2ban 0.9.6-2

I have created a tomcat8 filter to detect multiple 404 error

## /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/tomcat.conf :

```
[INCLUDES]
[Definition]
failregex =  ^<HOST>.*\/.*\/.*404
ignoreregex =
```

## /etc/fail2ban/jail.d/defaults-debian.conf :

```
[tomcat]
enabled  = true
port     = http,https,8080,8443
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8 MyIP/8 MyIP/16
bantime = 1728000
findtime = 5
filter   = tomcat
logpath  = /var/log/tomcat8/localhost_access_log.*.txt
maxretry = 3
```

The filter works but the problem is that it is possible that there is no access request to my tomcat web application during a day, so it is possible i don't have any log access for the day created by tomcat (i noticed the file is created when there is the first request)... So the file about fail2ban is working doesn't exist... for exemple i get this error :

```
2018-11-20 04:56:11,771 fail2ban.filterpoll     [18667]: ERROR   Unable to get stat on /var/log/tomcat8/localhost_access_log.2018-11-19.txt because of: [Errno 2] 
No such file or directory: '/var/log/tomcat8/localhost_access_log.2018-11-19.txt'
```

and fail2ban stop the my tomcat jail...

What is the best approach ?

- in a cron, detect if log access file exist, if no then create it for the day (touch approach with dateTime parameter)?
- script a curl request to force tomcat create the log access file, and force fail2ban to restart ?
- other ?

Comment: Your filter is susceptible to DoS, [FILTERS](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/0.11/FILTERS). Just ignore 404 errors, and I you have trouble, don't log them. It will allow you to focus on the users you care about.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [asciilog](https://asciilog.wordpress.com/2015/05/25/using-fail2ban-with-tomcat/) setup, just create a cron.
He experienced the same problem:

> 3. *Setup log rotation with cron*
>
>    *I’ve run into various bugs with the way Tomcat rotates log files, so I disable Tomcat’s log rotation and use cron...*

As you can see:

```
00 00 * * * /bin/cp /var/log/tomcat8/localhost_access_log.txt /var/log/tomcat8/localhost_access_log.$(/bin/date +\%Y-\%m-\%d -d "yesterday").txt && /usr/bin/truncate -s 0 /var/log/tomcat8/localhost_access_log.txt
```

*This will copy the contents of the log file to a new file, and then delete the contents of the original file. This event will be detected by fail2ban as a log rotation*